# How do I assign the next set of variables to the equation?

Tags: java, math

I had to create a program that reads data from a text file. I got it to read the first first variable and put it into the equation but am quite unsure how to set it for the rest.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
//   Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(new File("energyProduced.txt"));
        stdIn.nextDouble();
        double energy1;
        double energy2;
        double energy3;
        double energy4;
        double energy5;
        double energy6;
        double energy7;
        energy1 = stdIn.nextDouble();
        energy2 = stdIn.nextDouble();
        energy3 = stdIn.nextDouble();
        energy4 = stdIn.nextDouble();
        energy5 = stdIn.nextDouble();
        energy6 = stdIn.nextDouble();
        energy7 = stdIn.nextDouble();
   int systemsCost;  //Total Systems Cost
   double ttlEnergy; //Total energy produced in a week
   double savingsWeek; //Total savings for one week
   double savingsDay;  //Total savings for one day
   double recoupDay;  //Days to recoup
   double recoupYear; //Years to recoup
   final double electricCost = 0.085;
//

   ttlEnergy = (energy1 * 7);
   savingsWeek = (ttlEnergy * electricCost);
   savingsDay = (savingsWeek / 7);
   systemsCost = (int) (savingsWeek * energy1);
   recoupDay = (int) (systemsCost / savingsDay);
   recoupYear = (int) (recoupDay / 365);


//
    System.out.println("Total System Cost = $" + systemsCost );
    System.out.println("Total Energy Produced in one week" + (ttlEnergy) + "Kwh");
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one week =" + savingsWeek);
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one day =" + savingsDay);
    System.out.println("Days to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupDay);
    System.out.println("Years to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupYear);
    System.out.println();
```

it only reads energy1 not the rest 2-7, what should i do so that it reads the rest?
**Edit**
the .txt file is a list of numbers:
23(it only reads this one)
26
75
98
45
etc.

**EDIT2**

I did rewrote it a bit.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
//   Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(new File("energyProduced.txt"));
        stdIn.nextDouble();
        double energy1;
        double energy2;
        double energy3;
        double energy4;
        double energy5;
        double energy6;
        double energy7;
        energy1 = stdIn.nextDouble();
        energy2 = stdIn.nextDouble();
        energy3 = stdIn.nextDouble();
        energy4 = stdIn.nextDouble();
        energy5 = stdIn.nextDouble();
        energy6 = stdIn.nextDouble();
        energy7 = stdIn.nextDouble();
   int systemsCost;  //Total Systems Cost
   double ttlEnergy; //Total energy produced in a week
   double savingsWeek; //Total savings for one week
   double savingsDay;  //Total savings for one day
   double recoupDay;  //Days to recoup
   double recoupYear; //Years to recoup
   int systemsCost2;  //Total Systems Cost
   double ttlEnergy2; //Total energy produced in a week
   double savingsWeek2; //Total savings for one week
   double savingsDay2;  //Total savings for one day
   double recoupDay2;  //Days to recoup
   double recoupYear2; //Years to recoup
   int systemsCost3;  //Total Systems Cost
   double ttlEnergy3; //Total energy produced in a week
   double savingsWeek3; //Total savings for one week
   double savingsDay3;  //Total savings for one day
   double recoupDay3;  //Days to recoup
   double recoupYear3; //Years to recoup
   int systemsCost4;  //Total Systems Cost
   double ttlEnergy4; //Total energy produced in a week
   double savingsWeek4; //Total savings for one week
   double savingsDay4;  //Total savings for one day
   double recoupDay4;  //Days to recoup
   double recoupYear4; //Years to recoup
   int systemsCost5;  //Total Systems Cost
   double ttlEnergy5; //Total energy produced in a week
   double savingsWeek5; //Total savings for one week
   double savingsDay5;  //Total savings for one day
   double recoupDay5;  //Days to recoup
   double recoupYear5; //Years to recoup
   int systemsCost6;  //Total Systems Cost
   double ttlEnergy6; //Total energy produced in a week
   double savingsWeek6; //Total savings for one week
   double savingsDay6;  //Total savings for one day
   double recoupDay6;  //Days to recoup
   double recoupYear6; //Years to recoup
   int systemsCost7;  //Total Systems Cost
   double ttlEnergy7; //Total energy produced in a week
   double savingsWeek7; //Total savings for one week
   double savingsDay7;  //Total savings for one day
   double recoupDay7;  //Days to recoup
   double recoupYear7; //Years to recoup
   final double electricCost = 0.085;


   ttlEnergy = (energy1 * 7);
   savingsWeek = (ttlEnergy * electricCost);
   savingsDay = (savingsWeek / 7);
   systemsCost = (int) (savingsWeek * energy1);
   recoupDay = (int) (systemsCost / savingsDay);
   recoupYear = (int) (recoupDay / 365);
   ttlEnergy2 = (energy2 * 7);
   savingsWeek2 = (ttlEnergy * electricCost);
   savingsDay2 = (savingsWeek / 7);
   systemsCost2 = (int) (savingsWeek * energy2);
   recoupDay2 = (int) (systemsCost / savingsDay);
   recoupYear2 = (int) (recoupDay / 365);
   ttlEnergy3 = (energy3 * 7);
   savingsWeek3 = (ttlEnergy * electricCost);
   savingsDay3 = (savingsWeek / 7);
   systemsCost3 = (int) (savingsWeek * energy3);
   recoupDay3 = (int) (systemsCost / savingsDay);
   recoupYear3 = (int) (recoupDay / 365);
   ttlEnergy4 = (energy4 * 7);
   savingsWeek4 = (ttlEnergy * electricCost);
   savingsDay4 = (savingsWeek / 7);
   systemsCost4 = (int) (savingsWeek * energy4);
   recoupDay4 = (int) (systemsCost / savingsDay);
   recoupYear4 = (int) (recoupDay / 365);
   ttlEnergy5 = (energy5 * 7);
   savingsWeek5 = (ttlEnergy * electricCost);
   savingsDay5 = (savingsWeek / 7);
   systemsCost5 = (int) (savingsWeek * energy5);
   recoupDay5 = (int) (systemsCost / savingsDay);
   recoupYear5 = (int) (recoupDay / 365);
   ttlEnergy6 = (energy6 * 7);
   savingsWeek6 = (ttlEnergy * electricCost);
   savingsDay6 = (savingsWeek / 7);
   systemsCost6 = (int) (savingsWeek * energy6);
   recoupDay6 = (int) (systemsCost / savingsDay);
   recoupYear6 = (int) (recoupDay / 365);
   ttlEnergy7 = (energy7 * 7);
   savingsWeek7 = (ttlEnergy * electricCost);
   savingsDay7 = (savingsWeek / 7);
   systemsCost7 = (int) (savingsWeek * energy7);
   recoupDay7 = (int) (systemsCost / savingsDay);
   recoupYear7 = (int) (recoupDay / 365);


    System.out.println("Total System Cost = $" + systemsCost );
    System.out.println("Total Energy Produced in one week" + (ttlEnergy) + "Kwh");
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one week =" + savingsWeek);
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one day =" + savingsDay);
    System.out.println("Days to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupDay);
    System.out.println("Years to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupYear);
    System.out.println();   
    System.out.println("Total System Cost = $" + systemsCost2 );
    System.out.println("Total Energy Produced in one week" + (ttlEnergy2) + "Kwh");
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one week =" + savingsWeek2);
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one day =" + savingsDay2);
    System.out.println("Days to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupDay2);
    System.out.println("Years to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupYear2);
    System.out.println();   
    System.out.println("Total System Cost = $" + systemsCost3 );
    System.out.println("Total Energy Produced in one week" + (ttlEnergy3) + "Kwh");
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one week =" + savingsWeek3);
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one day =" + savingsDay3);
    System.out.println("Days to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupDay3);
    System.out.println("Years to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupYear3);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Total System Cost = $" + systemsCost4 );
    System.out.println("Total Energy Produced in one week" + (ttlEnergy4) + "Kwh");
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one week =" + savingsWeek4);
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one day =" + savingsDay4);
    System.out.println("Days to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupDay4);
    System.out.println("Years to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupYear4);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Total System Cost = $" + systemsCost5 );
    System.out.println("Total Energy Produced in one week" + (ttlEnergy5) + "Kwh");
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one week =" + savingsWeek5);
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one day =" + savingsDay5);
    System.out.println("Days to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupDay5);
    System.out.println("Years to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupYear5);
    System.out.println();   
    System.out.println("Total System Cost = $" + systemsCost6 );
    System.out.println("Total Energy Produced in one week" + (ttlEnergy6) + "Kwh");
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one week =" + savingsWeek6);
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one day =" + savingsDay6);
    System.out.println("Days to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupDay6);
    System.out.println("Years to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupYear6);
    System.out.println();   
    System.out.println("Total System Cost = $" + systemsCost7 );
    System.out.println("Total Energy Produced in one week" + (ttlEnergy7) + "Kwh");
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one week =" + savingsWeek7);
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one day =" + savingsDay7);
    System.out.println("Days to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupDay7);
    System.out.println("Years to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupYear7);
    System.out.println();   

 } // end main
```

It compiles alright but then it gives me the `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Do you mean that `stdIn.nextDouble()` doesn't work, or what?

Comment: @Gendarme it works? It gives me energy1 info. but not the rest

Comment: Are you sure? In your posted code, you aren't even using variables other than `energy1`. You did `ttlEnergy = energy1*7;` instead of `ttlEnergy = energy1 + energy2 + energy3 + energy4 + energy5 + energy6 + energy7;`.

Comment: @Gendarme oh okay that energy1*7 is part of the equation. I was wondering if there was another way to cycle through energy2-7. I thought about writing it all out and copying everything and pasting it (ttlEnergy2 = energy 2 * 7) like that but unsure if that was tedious or not.

Comment: It feels like this would be much easier to follow (and fix) with arrays and loops over them than with the same names and code 7 times.

Comment: You are hardcoding your problem, this could easily been resolved modularizing it, or even just using loops...

Comment: reindent your code properly

Answer (score 0):

This definitely looks a homework assignment. Here are a few pointers for you to help you on your way. Your code is very redundant and long, and as we know the amount of bugs in code is directly proportionate to the lines of code. So, the less lines of the code the better. There are data structures in java such as lists and arrays to help you our so you don't have to write every single variable you are going to use. I am not a senior developer, not do I claim to be an expert but this is how a mid level developer would go about tackling this problem. *note I didn't get a chance to compile this, because I was using notepad ++ and didn't have my other computer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {

     // i like to underscore my static final variables
     // so i know when i use them
    static final double _electricCost = 0.085;

    int systemsCost = 0;

    List<Double> energyProductList = new ArrayList();

    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("energyProduced.txt"));

    //to prevent the no such element error you need to make sure
    // there is an element to be had with

    while(fileScanner.hasNext())
    {
        //your values looked like ints so we'll use that
        int energyProduced = fileScanner.nextInt();
        energyProductList.add(energyProduced);
    }

    // now that we've grabbed all our energy values we can
    // iterate them and do the calculations we need

    // we will create some lists to contain our summary data

    List<Integer> weeklyEnergy = new ArrayList();
    List<Double> weeklySavings = new ArrayList();
    List<Double> savingsPerDay = new ArrayList();
    List<Double> systemsCost = new ArrayList();
    List<Integer> recoupDay = new ArrayList();
    List<Integer> recoupYear  = new ArrayList();


    for(int energy:energyProductList)
    {
        int tempWeeklyEnergy = energy * 7;
        double tempWeeklySavings = tempWeeklyEnergy * _electricCost;
        double tempSavingsPerDay = tempWeeklySavings / 7;
        double tempSystemsCost = tempWeeklySavings * energy;
        int tempRecoupDay = (int)(tempSystemsCost / tempSavingsPerDay);
        int tempRecoupYear = (int) (recoupDay / 365);


        //here we are putting all our calculated values in their corresponding
        // containers
        weeklyEnergy.add(tempWeeklyEnergy);
        weeklySavings.add(tempWeeklySavings);
        savingsPerDay.add(tempSavingsPerDay);
        systemsCost.add(tempSystemsCost);
        recoupDay.add(tempRecoupDay);
        recoupYear.add(tempRecoupYear);
    }

    //now that we have our values in nice lists so the length of them can be as big
    // or as small as they want we can print

    int max = energyProductList.size();
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter <= max)
    {   
    System.out.println("Energy -> " + counter)
    System.out.println("Total System Cost = $" + systemsCost.get(counter) );
    System.out.println("Total Energy Produced in one week" + (weeklyEnergy.get(counter)) + "Kwh");
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one week =" + weeklySavings.get(counter));
    System.out.println("Total Savings for one day =" + savingsPerDay.get(counter));
    System.out.println("Days to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupDay.get(counter));
    System.out.println("Years to recoup cost(truncated)" + recoupYear.get(counter));
    System.out.println();   
    }




 }
```

Comment: I compiled it but it gives a "cannot find symbol error" on the List. I imported the ArrayList as well.

Comment: Which line exactly?

Comment: List<Integer> weeklyEnergy = new ArrayList();
    List<Double> weeklySavings = new ArrayList();
    List<Double> savingsPerDay = new ArrayList();
    List<Double> systemsCost = new ArrayList();
    List<Integer> recoupDay = new ArrayList();
    List<Integer> recoupYear  = new ArrayList();

Comment: Did you import `import java.util.List;`